# Can I suggest a product of the company am working at?

Tags: support

So I want to answer this question - [iOS Remote Debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262236/ios-remote-debugging) and the company where am working right now provides a solution to that. Well, part solution, but they do.

I've already wrote an answer (in draft right now) but wanted to clarify before I post one. I've mentioned disclaimer at the top of the answer that I work at this company. So is it fine if I suggest a product of a company where am working at currently?

**Update** : [Posted an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262236/ios-remote-debugging/41608922#41608922) (I would appreciate if you guys want to edit it out if you feel that any part of my answer promotes the product in any way because English is not my native language and am bad at explaining products :p)

Comment: Over Meta ["Limits for self-promotion"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59302/178816)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So long as it is disclosed and is an actual answer (as in not just: I work at company A and here is a link that solves your problem [link]), that is fairly common.

Many companies make tools that are used in our industry, and it wouldn't make sense to not advocate for one of them if it solves a problem solely because of association.

Furthermore, perhaps this is just me, but I think that it is great to have developers who are involved in a product also involved here at Stack Overflow giving back to those who are trying to then use said product.

So, if that seems to sum up your approach to this question, then in my opinion (and from observation here over the years) there should be no problem.

Comment: Thanks, I've explained in detail that how to debug websites using devices which my company provides, cannot share how it actually works because of compliance restrictions.